# Slick carousel Icons showing DOT and AT but no icons

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

I am using Slick Carousel.

The carousel is working fine - works great!

However the icons are not displaying, the next and previous just say "AT" and the dots pagination just says "dots" with no icons!

Any ideas?

```
 Folder structure:
 root/index.html
 root/slick/[js /css]
 root/slick/fonts
```

CSS (Slick-theme.css)

```
/* Icons */
@font-face
{
       font-family: 'slick';
       font-weight: normal;
       font-style: normal;

       src: url('slick/fonts/slick.eot');
       src: url('slick/fonts/slick.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('slick/fonts/slick.woff') format('woff'), url('slick/fonts/slick.ttf') format('truetype'), url('slick/fonts/slick.svg#slick') format('svg');
}
```

JS

```
<script>
    $('.autoplay').slick({
        slidesToShow: 4,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        speed: 800,
        autoplay: true,
        autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="slider autoplay">
    <div><h3>1</h3></div>
    <div><h3>2</h3></div>
    <div><h3>3</h3></div>
    <div><h3>4</h3></div>
    <div><h3>5</h3></div>
    <div><h3>6</h3></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please, provide more information(HTML, CSS, Jquey, jsfiddle and etc).

Comment: Check the path of the icons

Comment: Hi see above, its the same folder structure as per download from git. Not sure if its the fonts from the theme.css, ive tried changing the fonts location but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify your character encoding. Add this in to the top of your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
```

Most browsers have a warning for this type of error in the console. Firefox:

> The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.